# Centering a google map by clicking on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I wish to center a google map by clicking on a div within the page that is not part of the map. I tried this but it did not work

```
$('#myDiv').click( function() {
    map.panTo(36.549362,-98.613281);
});
```

and i also tried this

```
$('#myDiv').click( function() {
    map.setCenter(36.549362,-98.613281);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like:

```
$('#myDiv').click( function() {
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(36.549362,-98.613281));
});
```

ie. you have to make a LatLng object first and pass that, instead of the raw coordinates.

I don't know what version of GMaps you're using but check the documentation.

[v3 Map doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), here you can see `setCenter` takes a `LatLng`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this also did not work. I'm beginning to think i need another step to make the click event 'talk' to the map?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set is up as a new `LatLng`

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(36.549362,-98.613281);

$('#resetMapDiv').click( function(event) {                  
    map.panTo(point);
});
```